# indexOf('?') for a list not working

Tags: list, scala, collections, scala-collections, indexof

I have to return the index of the first element in the list that contains the ’?’ character.

Why does it come up as -1 when it should be 8. Does indexOf not work on characters? Should I use indexWhere or will that have the same result?

```
scala> val lst = List("question?mark")
lst: List[String] = List(question?mark)

scala> lst.indexOf('?')
res2: Int = -1
```

When I make the val a string it works correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `lst.indexWhere(_.contains("?"))`

`indexOf` "Finds index of first occurrence of some value in this list." [link](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@indexOf(elem:A):Int)

Therefore it finds string that equals "?" in the list.

Comment: when i test this is scala it understands when there is not a question mark present by giving -1 but it keeps saying int = 0

Comment: "the index of the first element in the list that contains `?`" _is_ 0. In fact your list contains only one element.

Comment: @acolist, could you give your testcase where list items don't contain "?" and result is 0?

Answer (score 1):

`.indexOf` works on String

```
scala> "where is ?".indexOf('?')
res5: Int = 9
```

so try

```
lst(0).indexOf('?')
```

for each element of list you can use

```
scala> val lst = List("question?mark","where?","hello","why?")
lst: List[String] = List(question?mark, where?, hello, why?)

scala> lst.map(_.indexOf('?'))
res4: List[Int] = List(8, 5, -1, 3)
```

Comment: In this case you will find all elements that contains '?', not the first.